# How to create a view to code-first DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework

In Database-First, it is relatively easy to add views into the EDMX. How can we do it in Code-First?

We can create views using Code First in the custom migration class.

```
public partial class AddNewView : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("CREATE VIEW [dbo].[NewView] AS ...");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Sql("DROP VIEW dbo.[NewView]");
    }
}
```

But how can we access the view in the DbContext?

For tables, we can add domain models into DbContext and do some configuration,

```
public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfiguration());
}
```

What is the correct way to add the view into DbContext?

Comment: You can access them like tables. For EF it doesn't matter if "Person" is table or view.

Comment: Like `public virtual DbSet<MyView> Views { get; }`?

Answer (score 0):

It feels a bit hackish but what I end up doing is:

- Create a model with all the properties representing your view.
- Add the `public virtual DbSet<TableName> TableNames { get; }` to your `DbContext`
- Run `Add-Migration vwTableName`
- Remove the `Up()` and `Down()` methods from the migration.

And add the view creation/deletion SQL scripts:

```
public override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE VIEW [dbo].[NewView] AS ...");
}
public override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.Sql("DROP VIEW dbo.[NewView]");
}
```